# Changes to table not designed for SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I am supposed to do some changes to an enormous CSV file based on a different file. Therefore I chose to do it in SQL but after further consideration I am not sure how to proceed..

In the 1st table I have a list of contracts. Columns represent some segments the contract belongs to and some products that can be linked to the contract (example in the table below). 
Here contract no. 1234 belongs to segments X1 and Y2. There is no product number 1 linked to it, but it has product number 2 linked to it. The product originaly ends on the 1st of January 2030.

```
cont_n|date|segment_1|segment_2|..|prod_1|date_prod_1|product_2|date_product_2|..
1234  |3011| X1      | Y2      |..|      |           |YES      |01/01/2030    |..
```

The 2nd file is a list of combinations of segments and an indication how the "date" columns should be adjusted. The example shows following situation - if there is prod_2 linked to the contract which belongs to groups X1 and Y2, end the prod_2 this year. I need this result to alter table no. 1.

```
prod_no|segment_1|segment_2|result
prod_2 | X1      | Y2      | end the product on anniversary
```

Ergo I need to get to the result:

```
cont_n|date|segment_1|segment_2|..|prod_1|date_prod_1|product_2|date_product_2|..
1234  |3011| X1      | Y2      |..|      |           |YES      |30/11/2019    |..
```

In the original files I have around 600k rows and more than 300 columns (meaning around 100 different products) in table 1 and around 800 possible combinations of segments in table 2.

The algorithm I need to implement (very generally):

```
for x=1 to 100
IF product_x = YES THEN date_product_x = date + "Seach for result in table2"
```

Is there a reasonable way how to change the "date_product_x" columns based on the 2nd table or would it be better to find a different solution?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you a general approach, because the information in your question is general (for example, why does "end the product on anniversary" translate to "30/11/2019"?   It's not explained in the question, so I assume you're going to be able to handle that part of the logic).

You can approach this by using an UNPIVOT on Table 1 to get a structure like:

```
cont_n   |   segment1   |   segment2   |   product_number   |   product_date
```

You will UNPIVOT..FOR `date_product_1` thru `date_product_100`.   You'll either have to type out all 100 column names, or use dynamic sql to build the whole thing.

You'll do some string manipulation to grab the "x" portion of "date_product_x", and turn it into "prod_x", and then you can join to the second table on the two `segment` columns and the "prod_x" column, get the `result` column value, and do whatever rules you're doing to get the value you want for `date_product_x`.

Finally, you take that result, and PIVOT it back to the one-row-per-contract form, and JOIN it to your original table to UPDATE the `date_product_x` columns.